# Making twitter bootstrap modal totally modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap modal. However, I'm able to close it simply clicking on any area on a page. Even if I'm doing:

```
$("#ajaxModal").modal({keyboard: false, show: true});
```

it's not changing this behavior.

How do I make it totally modal meaning without ability to close it by clicking on a page or pressing Esc or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$("#ajaxModal").modal({
    keyboard: false,
    show: true,
    backdrop: 'static'
});
```

The [bootstrap doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) says about the backdrop property:

> Includes a modal-backdrop element. Alternatively, specify static for a
>   backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Bootstrap modal documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) it seems you need to add the option `backdrop: 'static'` to your options object:

```
  $("#ajaxModal").modal({keyboard: false, show: true, backdrop: 'static' });
```